# EF 6 Code First: Campo decimal dá erro ao tentar salvar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, code-first

Galera, bom dia.

Tenho uma classe que possui um campo decimal aonde eu guardo o preço. Até ai tudo bem. Quando ela é exibida no /Edit/ da pagina, também ta beleza. Só que eis o problema: 
1 - O MVC (que estou utilizando o 4 com EF 6) ele exibe no input o campo com ,00 dai quando vou salvar ele não deixa informando que o formato esta incorreto (validate do EF).
2 - Se eu coloco o .00, ele passa
3 - se for por algum valor do tipo: 14.90 (14,90 em real) ele manda pro banco 14900

Como poderia resolver este problema?

Segue a classe:

```
public class Opcional
{
    public Opcional()
    {
        this.Diarias = new HashSet<Diaria>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int OpcionalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Diaria> Diarias { get; private set; }
}
```

Trecho do codigo do meu edite:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor)</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Valor)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Valor)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

O caminho é implementar seu próprio *Model Binder*. Um *Model Binder* que uso para decimais está abaixo:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        object result = null;

        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        string attemptedValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

        string wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        string alternateSeperator = (wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",");

        if (attemptedValue.IndexOf(wantedSeperator) == -1
            && attemptedValue.IndexOf(alternateSeperator) != -1)
        {
            attemptedValue = attemptedValue.Replace(alternateSeperator, wantedSeperator);
        }

        try
        {
            result = decimal.Parse(attemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Crie esta classe no seu projeto e registre a classe no `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde Luis.

Estive pesquisando pois tive um problema similar e foi um pouco difícil de encontra algo que funcionasse.

Segui os passo descritos no link abaixo e consegui resolver meu problema.
https://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-manipulando-valores-monetarios/28907

Abs.